# How can I permit the Full-Text Search to search for conjuction?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, database, full-text-search

When I do a search like: People in England, the full-text search engine ignores the all search and returns 0 results. I think It is because It separetes each word ("People", "in" and "England") and ignores the "in" word because It may return many results.

I don't want the exact word ("People in England") but I'd like to find in the same text the words People, in and England.

Comment: Can you show your query? The way you construct the full text search phrase matters a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You want "in" keyword (like OR, AND, ...)be considered a simple word in criteria, right?

You must configure stopword for your fulltext query, here is as link about it:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/44032/searching-for-keywords-in-fulltext-indexes-using-the-contains-function